# Posgresql Select row with lowest value for specific column

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have the following table :

```
ID     SORT_ID     MY_DATE       USER_ID
10       1         01/01/2023      1
11       2         01/09/2023      1
13       3         15/08/2023      1
14       4         10/12/2023      1
```

i want to select (for the `USER_ID = 1`) the date of the row with the lowest `SORT_ID` which is the row with `SORT_ID = 1` and `ID = 10`

i tried this query but it returns the highest (row with : `SORT_ID = 4 and ID = 14` )

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (USER_ID)
MY_DATE 
FROM MY_TABLE where USER_ID = 1
ORDER BY USER_ID;
```

do you have any idea to adjust my select in order to get the lowest row (`USER_ID = 1 AND SORT_ID = 1 AND ID = 10` ) dynamically

Comment: Add some more sample data (perhaps another USER_ID value)m and also _specify_ the expected result - i.e. a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the order by clause in your query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (USER_ID)
MY_DATE 
FROM MY_TABLE where USER_ID = 1
ORDER BY USER_ID,SORT_ID;
```

Comment: thanks for your response but im getting error SQL Error [42P10]: ERROR: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
  Position : 21

Comment: yeah , add user_id also in order by

Comment: it works now, please could you add the select for getting the highest row with SORT_ID = 4

Comment: By what I understand you need to add 'desc' at the end. SELECT DISTINCT ON (USER_ID)
MY_DATE 
FROM MY_TABLE where USER_ID = 1
ORDER BY USER_ID,SORT_ID desc;

Comment: you are right this is what i did. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can simply :

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE USER_ID = 1
ORDER BY SORT_ID
LIMIT 1
```

Or use `group by` and `min()` :

First get the lowest SORT_ID of the user :

```
select USER_ID, min(SORT_ID) as min_id
from MY_TABLE
where USER_ID = 1
group by USER_ID
```

Then join it with the table to get the expected result :

```
select t.*
from MY_TABLE t
inner join (
  select USER_ID, min(SORT_ID) as min_SORT_ID
  from MY_TABLE
  where USER_ID = 1
  group by USER_ID
) as s on s.USER_ID = t.USER_ID and s.min_SORT_ID = t.SORT_ID
where t.USER_ID = 1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZsXua-RP)